# How can I get mysql2 to install?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, mysql2

I'm completely new to rails development and have been struggling with installing mysql2 with the past month. I'm have windows 8.1 64 bit, ruby 2.0.0p535 64bit, rails 4.0.2, and I have mysql2 (0.3.14) 64bit. The errors that I am getting from cmd are below.

```
C:\Users\tghol_000>gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector\"' --with-mysql         lib="C:\mysql-connector\lib"'
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector\" --with-mysql-lib=C:\mysql-    connector\lib'
    This could take a while...
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
        --with-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb:75:in `block in shellsplit': Unmatched double quote: "\"-IC:\\mysql-connector\" --with-mysql-lib=C:\\mysql-connector\\lib 2>&1/include\" -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 $(DEFS) $(cppflags)"
 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb:73:in `scan'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb:73:in `shellsplit'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1687:in `dir_config'
        from extconf.rb:42:in `' 
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector\" --with-        mysql-lib=C:\mysql-connector\lib
        checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
        checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()
        checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
        checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
        checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
        checking for rb_intern3()... yes

        extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.14/gem_make.out
```

mkmf.log

```
have_header: checking for ruby/thread.h... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <ruby/thread.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:9:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <ruby/thread.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: extern int t(void);
 9: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_call_without_gvl; return 0; }
10: int main(int argc, char **argv)
11: {
12:   if (argc > 1000000) {
13:     printf("%p", &t);
14:   }
15: 
16:   return 0;
17: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:1: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at C:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:841) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
conftest.c:8:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_blocking_region; return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:57: error: 'rb_wait_for_single_fd' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:8:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:8:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd; return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_wait_for_single_fd' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int t(void) { rb_wait_for_single_fd(); return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_hash_dup()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_hash_dup; return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_intern3()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:57: error: 'rb_intern3' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:8:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:8:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_intern3; return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_intern3' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int t(void) { rb_intern3(); return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: show your **mkmf.log**

Comment: @majioa. Just posted it. Also what exactly is the mkmf.log?

Comment: It seems that ruby has been not completely compiled...

Comment: @majioa How should i go about resolving that?

Comment: See here the trial manual of the man that encountered the similar problem: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/38765

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\tghol_000>gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector\"' --with-mysql         lib="C:\mysql-connector\lib"'
                                                                                                ^-- remove that '
```

You have got unnecessary apostrophe, I have checked where it is, remove and try again.

Comment: check the 's and "s.  The error states you have an unmatched double quote.  I don't use Windows for Rails development, but I do believe it is possible, regardless of what "The Rails 4 Way" says.